Talking to non mahram
Assalamu alaykum,
I hope this message finds you well. I have a question regarding maintaining contact with non-mahram individuals. I have some male friends' numbers saved in my phone, but I realize that we don't communicate frequently, if at all. Considering Islamic principles of modesty and decency, would it be advisable for me to delete their contact information, even if there's no immediate necessity for it?I would appreciate your insight on this matter.
JazakAllahu Khairan,

Alhamdulillah,
Deleting or keeping the contact information of non-mahram males (those not related to you in a way that prevents marriage) depends on a few factors:

The level and nature of interaction: If there is frequent unnecessary communication, chatting, or conversations beyond basic needs, it would be better to delete their contacts to prevent any situation that could lead to improper interactions or temptation.

Intentions and preventive measure: Even if interaction is minimal currently, keeping their contacts could manifest an intention to rekindle communication later on. Removing them eliminates that possibility and any related fitnah (temptation).

Necessity: If there is a valid reason to maintain their contacts, such as work, studies or other legal dealings, then it would be permissible while ensuring interactions remain within proper bounds.


In light of Islamic principles of hayaa' (modesty) and avoiding situations that could lead to sins, the juridically preferred stance would be to delete their contact information if there is no necessity or significant benefit in retaining it.
The Prophet ﷺ said: "Whoever believes in Allah and the Last Day, let him not be alone with a non-mahram woman." (Bukhari, Muslim)  While this hadith refers to being alone, it highlights the principle of preventive measures.
However, if there is a valid reason or need to maintain their contacts, ensure you firmly uphold Islamic moral boundaries in any communication. Always have sincere intentions and be mindful of avoiding any situation that could lead to impermissible interactions.
The bottom line is - be on the safe side by limiting contact with non-mahrams when possible, while maintaining proper conduct if interaction is necessary. May Allah grant you wisdom and steadfastness.
And Allah knows best!

You can talk to a non-mehram if there is a need. Talking via phone or messaging is safer than talking in person. I don't think that deleting his contact number is necessary unless you are tempted to do haram things like flirting with him. If it makes you feel better then go ahead.
